# Is there any way to make echarts value labels adaptive?

Tags: visualization, echarts, graph-visualization

[bad overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNnoi.png)
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fjg3e3)

In options of label or labelLayout we can only set paddings, direction(top, bottom, right, left), hide overlap or move it, but all in one direction. But I need something like this

[good overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKddr.png)

Is there a way to do this in echarts?

I read all documentation, try every option, but didn't find the solution